# Any Low Level Programming language based on java syntax and features?

Tags: java, c, programming-languages

Is there any low Level Programming language available based on java syntax and features?

Basically there should be no memory management and user should be able to access the memory directly.

But should maintain following features of java : 
1) platform Independence(should compile directly to native code according to the machine architecture for maintaining platform independence  rather than compiling to byte code ) 
2) There should be no JVM to manage the memory and resources.
3) should have exception throwing and catching mechanism.
4) should have inbuilt multi-threading and concurrency support.
5) harness the Java-API. 
6) Should have pointer support like C.

Basically I am looking for a mixture of C and Java, with Syntax and coding conventions like Java, object-oriented(may not be strictly object oriented), but should be as fast as C.

Is there any such language already built or being developed? with one or more features listed above?

Comment: Yes; it's called C.

Comment: Dennis created a master piece, hell of language :)

Comment: What do you mean by "harness the Java-API"? Any specific example of that?

Comment: You, by definition, can't "harness the Java API" without a java runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ sounds like your closest bet, however you won't get all of the things you want. Specifically, you don't get platform independence, native multi-threading, and the Java-API. However, you can use the boost libraries to help with these things.

If your motivation is purely based on performance, you should know that Java is really fast now-a-days. Are you absolutely sure that it'll be too slow for whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: @Lirik I am not sure how much it provides, but things like boost can probably really help with this.

Comment: Correct! I was just pointing out that the OP was looking for in-built support and that's simply not available in C++ (yet). Boost is probably the best option for portability.

Comment: @Lirik Well, the best option would be the C++ threading library itself, but you're right in that the language itself is not that immediately aware of multithreading (nothing compared to Java's `synchronized`, if you like it or not).

Comment: @Oleksi Well, for simple thread-level parallelism and asynchronous task execution you don't need boost and the C++ threading library should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

There is no language with the features you describe.

C-like languages:

- are compiled to object code
- require manual memory management
- do not use a virtual machine
- have limited support for exceptions
- have pointers

They do not have:

- built-in multi-threading (though see pthreads)
- do not "harness the Java API"

Go and D are C-like, but with support for multi-threading and concurrency, though with garbage collector. Other systems-oriented languages such as ATS, Java and Haskell are similar -- you either get the raw machine, or you get some nice features and garbage collection. All have been used for systems programming.

So, either you go with C or C++, and the pain that entails, or you accept memory management.

Answer (score 1):

The [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) programming language is perhaps close to what you mean.

It's not platform-independent (that would be very hard for any low level systems programming language). It does have semi-automatic memory management, but not through garbage collection. It's an object oriented programming language that compiles to plain C and that uses the GNOME GObject system for its object oriented features.

It doesn't have anything to do with Java, so it does not provide the standard Java API for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only relevant language is Objective C, since it combines C with ideas from SmallTalk and inspired Java.

While you can use it as platform-independently as C, most of the ecosystem nowadays is for Apple platforms - but that's not a property of the language.

It can't use the Java API, but then no non-JVM language can.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is "D":

http://dlang.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any low Level Programming language available based on java syntax and features?

I would and have used Java for this. ;)

> Basically there should be no memory management

There is nothing forcing you to create garbage, you can recycle everything (or almost everything) yourself and with a large eden size avoid using the GC for a day or even a week. (Or restart the application and never use it)

> user should be able to access the memory directly.

For this I use ByteBuffers (supported) or Unsafe (not supported)

> But should maintain following features of java :
>   1) platform Independence(should compile directly to native code according to the machine architecture for maintaining platform independence rather than compiling to byte code )

The JVM does this.

> 2) There should be no JVM to manage the memory and resources.

You don't have to use the JVM directly.

> 3) should have exception throwing and catching mechanism.

The JVM does this.

> 4) should have inbuilt multi-threading and concurrency support.

The JVM does this.

> 5) harness the Java-API.

The JVM does this.

> 6) Should have pointer support like C.

You can do this with JVMs which have Unsafe available.  However you are likely to find that direct ByteBuffers will do what you want safely.

> but should be as fast as C.

Java is not as fast as C can be, given any amount of time and resources. However if you have limited time and resources, Java can help you have a fast enough, working and maintainable program in less time than a lower level language. (The same argument applies for higher level languages e.g. Scala vs Java BTW)